# Is it possible to use variable as @JsonRootName?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I have a spring project and class like that and want to produce json with root name as type. Here is an example:

```
public class Person {
  private String type; //worker
  private String name; //Dennis
  private String surname; //Ritchie
}
```

Result should be:

```
{"worker" : {
   "name" : "Dennis" ,
   "surname" : "Ritchie"
   }
}
```

Can I do it with Json tags like @JsonRootName or should I write a Class for worker and extend Person class (There are 3 different types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom Serializer when you need to serialize a object into a JSON with a different form:

```
public class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Person person, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) 
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeFieldName(person.getType());
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeFieldName("name", person.getName());
        jgen.writeFieldName("surname", person.getSurname());
        jgen.writeEndObject();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

After that, you can register the serializer on the class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = PersonSerializer.class)
public class Person {
    private String type; 
    private String name; 
    private String surname; 
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid calling `writeFieldName` for every single field in the POJO? It seems silly to have to copy everything over just for the sake of adding a single additional field (not to mention having to remember to update fields in two places should the POJO change).